# Display the character in a column?

Tags: sql-server

I have a column with names

### name

Jason
Mark

I am looking to get an output like

### Split

J
a
s
o
n
M
a
r
k

Is it possible to perform the above in a single SQL statement irrespective of the length of the string. The platform I work is MSSQL server.

Comment: SQL is not used to that kind of operations. Do that in your logic.

Comment: I just want to know if it is possible? It is okay if you do't know the answer!

Comment: it's possible, but not in a simple select, you'd need to write a stored procedure, and even then it's likely not recommended

Comment: So in a simple select statement it is not possible to do the above? Hmmmm.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: @infestation: I know that it is ok if I do not know the answer. Thank you. The point is: SQL is not used for such data manipulation. Don't do it. Use another language for it like Java or C#...

Comment: I know you should't do it. SQL has a different purpose. But this question was like kind of a itch I wanted to scratch, never gone use it in production.

Comment: @  Vladimir Oselsky I said using a simple select statement, how can it be a duplicate? The link you have posted is a different context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but not with a single SELECT statement.

A relatively easy way to do it would be using a SQLCLR stored procedure that will make the query, manipulate the resultset in a .NET language like C# and return it as any other resultset.

You also could do some serious TSQL-fu in a traditional stored proc that will loop through your data and store every characters in a memory table that will thereafter be returned as the resultset.

If you ask if it can be done in a single SELECT statement without using functions or procedures of any kind, then the answer is: **it's not possible**. And as juergen mentions in the comments above, it shouldn't be the job of the server to manipulate data in such a way.

Comment: I want a simple sql statement, no procedures, cte or functions.

Comment: @infestation I edited my answer. You won't like it but that's still the answer. :p